# What to do when my disc can fail? Should merge partitions?

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted

I am coming across a problem with my disc space, but when I try to resize or merge my partitions I cannot. I've tried many solutions like using GParted to resize or merge, but it is locked and I do not have a CD to do another action.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuaaG.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADXpl.jpg

P.S: I am not using dual boot or windows.

Comment: You can't modify partitions whilst booted to them. Never mind, your Ubuntu partition is not full. What makes you think that you have a disk space problem? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

Your partition is already maximum size at 160 GB. There is still 136 GB free, so it is difficult to understand why you have a problem with your disk space. If you have a problem with your disk space, then you will need to buy additional storage to store your data.

On the fact that it is locked: obviously, you cannot resize a partition while it is in use. To resize partitions, you either work from a live session started using an installation DVD or USB, or you use the command line tools in a recovery prompt. If you do not have a CD to do another action, then your only option will be the command line. See `apropos partition` for a list of command line tools to deal with partitions.

Comment: Look closer and you'll see that their Ubuntu partition is only using a small fraction of the 160G allocated.

Comment: @heynnema You are right, the first part was confusing. I now explicitly commented that there is still a lot of space free and that it is difficult to understand why there is a problem with disk space. Unclear question anyway.